Airflow postgres not able to connect
I have airflow setup to run in a docker container using the CeleryExecutor
Running a docker compose up on an AWS EC2 instance results in the following output:
The output will just hang on the following line
airflow-postgres  | 2024-06-04 03:46:35.160 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

running docker ps -a gives the following
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                                       NAMES
6a0f67a3ca39   airflow-triggerer      "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 minutes ago   Created                                                                       airflow-triggerer
cd8bb69de664   airflow-worker         "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 minutes ago   Created                                                                       airflow-worker
5c07c4483c87   airflow-scheduler      "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 minutes ago   Created                                                                       airflow-scheduler
b0cfd862eb66   airflow-webserver      "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   6 minutes ago   Created                                                                       airflow-webserver
92c67855406d   airflow-airflow-init   "/bin/bash -c 'airfl…"   6 minutes ago   Created                                                                       airflow-init
98e714c7e365   postgres:13            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes (unhealthy)          5432/tcp                                    airflow-postgres
3b48e8e6208c   redis:7.2.3            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes (health: starting)   6379/tcp                                    airflow-redis
6375b1d3dc4a   bobrik/socat           "socat TCP4-LISTEN:2…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes                      0.0.0.0:2376->2375/tcp, :::2376->2375/tcp   docker-proxy

here is a copy of my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env    
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - /home/ubuntu/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - /home/ubuntu/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - /home/ubuntu/airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - /home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
    - /home/ubuntu/.ssh/airflow-with-docker-1.pem:/opt/airflow/airflow-with-docker-1.pem

  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
  env_file:
      - .env

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: airflow-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always  

  redis:
    image: redis:7.2.3
    container_name: airflow-redis
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  docker-proxy:
    image: bobrik/socat
    container_name: docker-proxy
    command: "TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - "2376:2375"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    container_name: airflow-webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env

  scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    container_name: airflow-scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    env_file:
      - .env

  worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker && bash -c "sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock"
    container_name: airflow-worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8793:8793"
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    container_name: airflow-triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    << : *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow-init
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - airflow db init && 
        airflow users create
        --role Admin
        --username airflow
        --password airflow
        --email airflow@airflow.com
        --firstname airflow
        --lastname airflow
    restart: on-failure

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
  airflow-logs:

my airflow.cfg
[core]
executor = CeleryExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
dags_are_paused_at_creation = true
load_examples = false
load_default_connections = false
fernet_key = 

[database]
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow

[celery]
result_backend = db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
broker_url = redis://:@redis:6379/0

I'm pretty stuck as this same code is running fine on my local machine, and the code was running earlier in the day - I didn't change anything. Just did a simple docker compose down and now I'm unable to get airflow back up and running.
What am I missing?

Your docker-proxy container is a major security hole – anyone who can reach the host system port 2376, running an unencrypted unauthenticated Docker-over-HTTP service, can all but trivially root the entire host system.  Is it possible your host system is compromised?

What problem are you running into; what's the exact error message you're getting yout?  You have a pretty complex Compose setup, is it possible to reduce this to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem?
